# fix unsuppported characters using java

Tags: java, character-encoding, ms-word, special-characters

The charset of the Oracle database of the application I use is WE8ISO8859P1.

I think this is the oracle name for char set iso-8859-1.

The application exports some data into a word document which has boxes instead of bullet point characters. I want to remove these invalid boxes and replace them with bullet characters.

I have another java function to do find and replace this exported word document.

The function accepts an XML file, which contains the key value pairs, KEY for FIND string and VALUE for REPLACE string fields.

I decided to use this find and replace function to replace the invalid characters into proper bullet characters. This function used the native find and replace function of MS Word.

I am able to get that bullet character is represented by the string "^0149". So I pass on the replace string as "^0149".

Now I want to know what should be the character to find the invalid boxes, and i will pass on that character into the xml file.

Comment: Why don't you fix the export instead? It would be the correct thing to do, and your approach breaks if there's more than one kind of character that gets converted to a box.

Comment: yes you are right. But we don't have access to the code used by the Application, and we are customizing this application as an Eclipse plugin. So i can afford to play around with the exported document. Moreover the application documentation suggests to use CP1252 charset to avoid this problem, which is impossible for us right now. And I get the problem only in bullet characters and the rest looks fine.

Comment: `Alt+x` should show (in hexadecimal) Unicode codepoint value for any character _right before_ the insertion point (keyboard cursor). For instance, `Alt+x` applied to `•` bullet shows `2022`. What value would be shown if `Alt+x` is applied to that _invalid box_ in Microsoft Word?